# mutagen monitor Status: [Problems] Watching for changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mutagen

We've just started using Mutagen with docker for our projects and on the current project I'm working on I get the following error when I run `mutagen monitor`.

```sh
Status: [Problems] Watching for changes
```

It's not causing any issues as far as I can see, but I would like to know if/how it is possible to fix this so there is a status without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Running `mutagen sync list` will give you additional information about your specific problem